# probability of a flipped coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A fair coin is flipped three times. Let $A$ be the event that a head occurs in the first flip and $B$ be the event that exactly one head occurs.

a) Find $p(A/B)$

b) Are $A$ and $B$ independent?

### Proof:

a) Now we have $$p(A/B)=\frac{p(A \cap B)}{p(B)}$$
but
$p(A \cap B)=p(H,\bar{H},\bar{H})=\frac18$
and 
$p(B)=\frac38$,
so we obtain
$p(A/B)=\frac13.$

b) We have, 
$$p(A)=p(H,H,H)+p(H,H,\bar{H})+p(H,\bar{H},\bar{H})+p(H,\bar{H},H)=\frac12$$
so, $A$ and $B$ are not inndependent.

Is my work correct?

Comment: How did you calculate $P(B)$?

Comment: $p(B)=p(H,\bar{H},\bar{H})+p(\bar{H},H,\bar{H})+p(\bar{H},\bar{H},H)=\dfrac38$ @5xum

Answer (score 1):

We have $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$ where, as you stated, $$P(A \cap B) = P(H, \bar H, \bar H) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^2 = \frac{1}{8}$$
and $$P(B) = \binom{3}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^2 = \frac{3}{8}$$ which gives $$P(A|B) = \frac{1}{3}$$

we know that $$P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B) $$ if $A$ and $B$ are independent, this comes from 
$$
P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B) \Leftrightarrow P(A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} \Leftrightarrow P(A) = P(A|B)
$$
 Which can only be true if $A$ and $B$ are independent.

we calculate $$P(A) = P(H) = \frac{1}{2}$$
and conclude that $$P(A) \cdot P(B) = \frac{3}{16} \neq \frac{1}{8}$$
Q.E.D

Answer (score 0):

$P(A)$ can be calculated much simpler, as it is simply $P(H)=\frac12$, and you should elaborate some more how you got $P(B)$ to equal $\frac38$.

Also, you did not explain why $A$ and $B$ are dependent, you just threw a couple of numbers down. You must explain why those numbers imply that $A$ and $B$ are not independent.

Comment: $p(A \cap B)=\dfrac18 \neq \dfrac{3}{16}=p(A)p(B)$ @5xum

Comment: @A.MAKKI Then you are done and your work is correct and complete. But without writing what you wrote in the comment, your work would be incomplete.